# Serialization v/s Parcelable Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

Working on a project for caching. Would like to do it with file system on Android.
I know database is also a option but want to give try to file systems.

Making a object serializable in case of Android its very easy to use the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream to serialize and deserialize entrire arraylist of objects happens automatically.

It also allows passing of objects between two activities. However the load time of my application has increased by a ratio of 5 when reading a 250 node list.

I know parcelable also does the passing part and is Android's way for serialization. However, anyone has ideas how to use parcelable along with ObjectOutputStream so that full utilization of the Android's serialization can be used.

Also if anyone has ideas how to speed up serialization apart for readObject and writeObject please share. And by doing this how much of a difference can be achieved and is it advisable to do so.

Or is the database way the only option for caching in case of android. Not to forget pre-caching can also be achieved via db but we can?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use parcels. Per the Android Documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) :

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance [IPC transport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Making an object implement the serializable interface is risky too because then you're tied to that serialization format. If you change the object in the future, you're going to have issues reading in objects that were serialized under the old regime.

Using a database is probably your best option for caching things to disk.

Comment: if you don't like sqlite, have a look at http://www.db4o.com/ its open source and - for android completly free -. You can just save Objects like save(Object o) and retrieve like get(MyOwnObject.class) to get all stored Objects

Comment: You mean serialization is risky if you pass your objects to a server? Activity to Activity serialization is much safer.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this statement please?

Comment: @Blundell no I mean implementing the serialization interface is risky, period. For details on the perils of implementing the serializable interface checkout out http://macchiato.com/columns/Durable4.html

Comment: @Kurtis Ah of course if a user serializes some data with v1.3 an you change your object an release 1.4 you can lose what they saved. Thanks for the link, my bedtime reading tonight ;-)

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum I wont mind losing the data as i can always go and fetch it from the net via a webservice. Should have mentioned that in the question, my mistake. AS the data which i was planning to cache is not modifiable by user so wouldn't be much of a hassle if lost.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it works, so its just an idea:
try to use the [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) Object itself:

retrieve a new instance with `Parcel.obtain`

write all your Parcelable Objects with `writeToParcel(Parcel source)`

then if you wanna write the values to fileSystem call `marshall()` to get Bytes.

write it down with ByteInputStream or something similar

read it again, call unmarshall, and call the ParcelableCreators

Answer (score 0):

1. Serialization is slow because it uses reflection, which is very slow. You can only avoid this if you avoid serialization altogether.
2. ObjectOutputStream can produce byte array via ByteArrayOutputStream. Then you can use [`parcel.writeByteArray(byte[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D%29) to save byte array to parcel. This will would still be slow.

Comment: But to use ObjectOutputStream dont we need a object which implements serializable instead of parcelable?

Comment: You can have Parcelable on your wrapper object and Serializable in all objects that you actually want to store.

Comment: I wont need a parcelable than at all, i can just use Serializable. But as i mentioned for a 250 node tree it would take 5 sec instead of 1 sec earlier. Decreases performance considerable. The 5 sec is while loading it from the file system not in passing between activities.